# Simulating mouse hover on html image grid during parsing of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a small html parser for a webpage containing images displayed using image grid.
Each image can further queried using image-id in subsequent request. Though the web-page is displaying images 
on image-grid with corresponding image-id in html source I'm not able to find any reference to those images.
Also when I hover mouse on each of the image I can see the next link for each image made-up of image-id.
Can someone suggest me how I get the hidden image id directly in html page so that I can parse them.
On html page I just found this empty imagegrid. Apart from this there are many javascript etc.

```
<div id="imageGrid"></div>

<br>
```

Comment: Can you formulate what exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm looking for the links of images from imageGrid so that I can parse subsequent actual image html page. Though I'm able to see thumbnail and corresponding image-id in browser. I don't find any of this information in html source.